# Firebase cloud functions not working properly?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I writed a firebase cloud functions but its working only 70% when i do multiple delete !  and it's very slow ? what im doing wrong ??

here is my function :

```
exports.deleteQuestion = functions.database.ref('questions_for_mars/{pushId}').onDelete(event => {
  const original = event.val()
  idQuestion = event.key
  authorQuestion = original.author
  //console.log('event', original.answers)

  admin.database().ref('counter/questions_active').once('value').then((snapshot) => {


    var questions_active = snapshot.val()

    var updateQuestions = {};

    event.child('answers').forEach(child => {

      var mars = child.key
      updateQuestions['/my_answers/' + mars + '/' + idQuestion] = null
      updateQuestions['/mars/' + mars + '/counter/answers_active'] = questions_active - 1


      console.log('question active', original)
    });



    updateQuestions['/counter/questions_active'] = questions_active - 1
    updateQuestions['/my_questions/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null
    updateQuestions['/my_questions_send/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null
    updateQuestions['/questions/' + idQuestion] = null
    //updateQuestions['/my_answers/' + authorQuestion + '/' + idQuestion] = null

    console.log('UPDAYE', updateQuestions)
    return admin.database().ref().update(updateQuestions)

  })


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're obliged to return a promise from the top level of your callback function that resolves only after all the asynchronous work is complete.

```
return admin.database().ref('counter/questions_active').once(...).then(...)
```

This promise signals to Cloud Functions when it's OK to tear down the function and clean up.  If you don't return a promise correctly, it will clean up before the work is complete.

Comment: seems to work thanks ! :) is it a good pratice to do like i did or there is a better way ?

Comment: You can do it any way you want, so long as the function returns a promise that resolves only after all the work is complete.